# Calculate time needed for point to move outside of circle

Tags: trigonometry

I need to caluclate the time needed for a given point **A** (x,y) to move out of the given circle **B** (x,y,r). The speed of the point **A** is given by the change of **x** and **y** per second.

At the beginning I calculated if the point **A** is even in circle **B**, which was not hard given the formular: $$(x_A - x_B)^2 + (y_A - y_B)^2 < r^2$$

Then I thought of a way to calculate not only if the point is outside the circle, but when it's outside the circle by adding the coordinate of the movement into the equation. Let's say the speed of the point **A** is $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ and time is $t$. I then tried to add this to the equation to $x_A$ and $y_A$: $$(x_A + \Delta x * t - x_B)^2 + (y_A + \Delta y * t - y_B)^2 < r^2$$

Since then I am trying to figure out how to extract the time $t$ to calculate it, but I have been stuck. Is this even the right/best way to calculate it?

I am using it in programming, so there are certainly some dirty hacks I could use (calculation in for-loops) - but those would be ugly and I want to understand the mathematics behind it.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** I have managed to calculate the time needed with specific values, but I couldn't extract a specific formular to caluclate the time for any given value of **A** and **B** - not only the values I chose for the calculation.

Comment: If $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$ do not change over time, it should be possible to find the required time.

Comment: @Vasya yes $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ do not change over time, so I'm fairly certain it should be possible, I just don't know how

Comment: This will be a quadratic formula in $t$. Focus on which terms have a $t^2$ factor, or a $t$ factor, or no $t$, remembering that all your other variables have specific values, so you can treat expressions with them like coefficients.

Comment: @aschepler Yes thanks, I tried that once but didn't get a clean solution - I'll give it another try!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: assuming that point $A$ is inside the circle and $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$ do not change over time, we need to solve the quadratic equation: $(x_A + t\Delta x - x_B)^2 + (y_A + t\Delta y - y_B)^2 = r^2$ or $$t^2\left((\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2\right)+2t\left(\Delta x(x_A-x_B)+\Delta y(y_A-y_B)\right)+(x_A-x_B)^2+(y_A-y_B)^2-r^2=0$$ This quadratic may have one, two or no solutions depending on the position of point $A$. Let's say $t_1, t_2$ are the solutions. Obviously we are interested in positive solutions.

Comment: Thank you, your calculation helps me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Expand the left hand side of the inequality to get a quadratic equation with the variable $t$, and the coefficients in terms of $\Delta x, \Delta y, x, y$. Subtract $r^2$ from both sides to get an inequality in the form:
\begin{equation}
ax^2+bx+c-r^2<0
\end{equation}
Because $a$ would be positive, the interval between the roots of this quadratic equation would yield the time that the point will stay in the circle.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I have managed to solve it now! Is there a chance you know how to extract the time $t$ to get a formular to caluclate the time for any given value for A and B?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by "any given value for A and B"? Thanks.

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to extract a dedicated formular to solve for $t$. Rather than having to manually code a programm which expands the inequality and then solves it via quadratic equation for every time I want to calculate the needed time $t$ for any other points/circles.
But I recon I can just do that as well, and it should work too - Thanks anyways!